# IoTAgent (JSON) over MQTT doesn't receive measurements from mosquitto

Tags: json, docker-compose, mqtt, mosquitto, fiware

Goal: to use the IoTAgent (JSON) provided by FIWARE with the MQTT transport protocol. In particular, I would like to provision a service group rather than individual devices, such that anonymous devices can send their measurements to the IoTAgent via the Mosquitto Broker.

Problem: Mosquitto Broker receives messages (sent by an MQTT publisher) but IoTAgent does not. Both are on the same network (I used docker compose), so ruled out this could be the reason of the problem.

The docker-compose.yaml file looks like this:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.14
    hostname: mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    expose:
      - "1883"
      - "9001"
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      - default

  iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-json:latest
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
      - mosquitto
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "4041"
    ports:
      - "4041:4041"
    environment:
      - IOTA_CB_HOST=orion
      - IOTA_CB_PORT=1026
      - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=ld
      - IOTA_JSON_LD_CONTEXT=http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld
      - IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041
      - IOTA_MQTT_HOST=mosquitto
      - IOTA_MQTT_PORT=1883
      - IOTA_MQTT_QOS=1
      - IOTA_MQTT_KEEPALIVE=60
      - IOTA_DEFAULT_RESOURCE= # Default is blank. I'm using MQTT so I don't need a resource
      - IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb
      - IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db
      - IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27017
      - IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentjson
      - IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true
      - IOTA_AUTOCAST=true
      - IOTA_FALLBACK_TENANT=openiot
```

The full docker-compose.yaml is available on [GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/francesco.vignola.dev/traffic-flow-monitoring-system/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml).

The service group provisioning is shown below:

```
{
    "services": [
        {
            "apikey": "4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
            "entity_type": "TrafficFlowObserved",
            "resource": "",
            "expressionLanguage": "jexl",
            "attributes": [
                {"name": "id", "type": "Text", "expression": "'urn:ngsi-ld:TrafficFlowObserved:'+idelem"},
                {"name": "dateObserved", "type": "Text", "expression": "fecha_hora_inicio|toisodate+'/'+fecha_hora_finalizacion|toisodate"},
                {"object_id": "intensidad", "name": "intensity", "type": "Number"}
            ]
        }
    ]   
}
```

I expect the IoTAgent to receive measurements from anonymous devices as well as mosquitto. Instead, currently, the IoTAgent does not receive the measurements and gives the following error when I provision the service group: DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND.

The logs are shown on [GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/francesco.vignola.dev/traffic-flow-monitoring-system/blob/main/example/logs.txt)

I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide the IoTAgent service group provision and also how you are sending the data from device to the broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption you have provisioned a device as follows:

```bash
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/services' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
 "services": [
   {
     "apikey":      "4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
     "cbroker":     "http://orion:1026",
     "entity_type": "Thing",
     "resource":    ""
   }
 ]
}'
```

```bash
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
 "devices": [
   {
     "device_id":   "motion001",
     "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Motion:001",
     "entity_type": "Motion",
     "protocol":    "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
     "transport":   "MQTT",
     "timezone":    "Europe/Berlin",
     "attributes": [
       { "object_id": "c", "name": "count", "type": "Integer" }
     ]
   }
 ]
}'
```

You will need to post your data to the `/json/<api-key>/<device-id>/attrs` topic. It is important to include both the correct **protocol** `json` and the correct `<api-key>` - the message body is something like `{"c": 1}`.

This can be used to test the IoT Agent South Port without an actual device - assuming it works, you can then check that the Device is posting to the correct topic.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been busy. I reply with this comment to both you and @mapedraza.

I'm only interested in service group provisioning, using autoprovision for individual devices. But I was wrong in the creation of the topic.

In particular, I created the topic as `/json/apiKey/attrs`, without the `device-id`. Fixing the topic, everything works!

Thank you